# Get 10 random items from nested object that don't repeat

Tags: javascript

so, I have a "database" like this:

```
var db = {
  cars: [
    {brand: 'x', color: 'blue'},
    {brand: 'y', color: 'red'}
  ],
  pcs: {
    allInOne: [
      {brand: 'z', ram: '4gb'},
      {brand: 'v', ram: '8gb'}
    ],
    desktop: [
      {brand: 'a', ram: '16gb'},
      {brand: 'b', ram: '2gb'}
    ]
  }
}
```

As you can see, there can be subcategories. Of course my "database" is bigger than that. But the concept is the same. I need to get 3 random items from the object, and store them with the categorie, and subcategorie if it exists, like this:

```
var random = [
  {categorie: 'cars', subcategorie: null, product: {...}},
  {categorie: 'cars', subcategorie: null, product: {...}},
  {categorie: 'pcs', subcategorie: 'desktop', product: {...}}
]
```

Also, I need that they don't repeat. How can I achieve this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The example you give seems to repeat the 'cars' category!

Comment: @rasmeister yes, the categorie can be repeated, but not the product

Comment: My suggestion would be to create a complete flattened array first, then it's easy to shuffle and splice

Comment: And by product you mean the 'brand', etcetera?

Comment: @hackerrdave using a while loop, as long as the amount of products in the `random` array is less than `3` for example, I keep iterating through the object, but the code is a mess and it dind't lead me anywhere :(

Comment: @rasmeister yes

Comment: @charlietfl I thought that too but how can I keep track of the categorie and subcategorie?

Comment: `Object.keys(db).map(category...` then check if it's array or object

Comment: Must they be random?

Comment: How deep could a product be? How many levels there could be?

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir yes it must be random, and it can only be categorie and subcategorie, there is no be sub-subcategorie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function getRandom(db, num) {
  // FIRST: get an array of all the products with their categories and subcategories
  var arr = []; // the array
  Object.keys(db).forEach(function(k) { // for each key (category) in db
    if(db[k] instanceof Array) {        // if the category has no subcategories (if it's an array)
      db[k].forEach(function(p) {       // then for each product p add an entry with the category k, sucategory null, and the product p
        arr.push({categorie: k, subcategorie: null, product: p});
      });
    }
    else {                                      // if this caegory has subcategories
      Object.keys(db[k]).forEach(function(sk) { // then for each sucategory
        db[k][sk].forEach(function(p) {         // add the product with category k, subcategory sk, and product p
          arr.push({categorie: k, subcategorie: sk, product: p});
        })
      });
    }
  });

  // SECOND: get num random entries from the array arr
  var res = [];
  while(arr.length && num) { // while there is products in the array and num is not yet acheived
    var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length); // get a random index
    res.push(arr.splice(index, 1)[0]); // remove the item from arr and push it into res (splice returns an array, see the docs)
    num--;
  }
  return res;
}


var db = {cars: [{brand: 'x', color: 'blue'},{brand: 'y', color: 'red'}],pcs: {allInOne: [{brand: 'z', ram: '4gb'},{brand: 'v', ram: '8gb'}],desktop: [{brand: 'a', ram: '16gb'},{brand: 'b', ram: '2gb'}]}};

console.log(getRandom(db, 3));
```

Comment: You're a damn genius! Thank you!

Comment: @PeterZelak You're welcome! I added comments if you're intressted!